# Error: Invalid interceptor passed to @UseInterceptors() decorator (PermissionsController)

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I have an error in my **Interceptor**, when I call it within my controller it does not generate an error

interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class PermissionsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    // constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<unknown> {
        console.log('Before...');

        const now = Date.now();
        return next
            .handle()
            .pipe(
                tap(() => console.log('After: ',now)),
            );
    }
}
```

here called my controller

permissions.controller

```
import { Body, Controller, Delete, Get, Param, Post, Put, UseGuards, UsePipes, Headers, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';

import { PermissionsService } from './backend-permission.service';
//llamado a las rutas a traves de urls
import { URLS } from "@i-andes/shared/urls";
//Llamado a la libreria de validacion
// eslint-disable-next-line @nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries
import { CustomValidationPipe, RolesGuard, PermissionsInterceptor } from "@i-andes/backend/utils-backend";
import { PermissionsValidation, PermissionsActDesValidation, PermissionsUpdateValidation } from '../validations/PermissionsValidation';
import { ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { ResponseDTO } from '@i-andes/shared/dtos';


@ApiTags('Permission')
@Controller()
@UseGuards(RolesGuard)
export class PermissionsController {
  constructor(private readonly PERMISSIONS_SERVICE: PermissionsService) {}

  //Metodo encargado de listar todos los permisos
  @Get(URLS.listPermission)
  @UseInterceptors(PermissionsInterceptor)
  getPermission(@Headers() headers: string): Promise<ResponseDTO> {
      return this.PERMISSIONS_SERVICE.getPermission();
  }
}
```

Here error:
***throw new InvalidDecoratorItemException(decorator, item, context.name);***
^
***Error: Invalid interceptor passed to @UseInterceptors() decorator (PermissionsController).***

Comment: It looks like the interceptor is part of it's own package, is that correct? If so, do you have `@nestjs/common` and `@nestjs/core` as `peerDependencies` for the package?

Comment: How did you solve it?